# reflect image, I keep getting UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address

Tags: c, filter, cs50

I am making a filter program, first I did a grayscale and it worked pretty well. my problem is in the reflect filter (a reflect filter where the resulting image is what you would get by placing the original image in front of a mirror). my code is all good but I am not sure why I keep getting a UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL, and SEGV on unknown address...

```
#include "helpers.h"
#include <math.h>

// Convert image to grayscale
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        int average = round(image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtBlue) / 3;
        image[i][j].rgbtRed = average;
        image[i][j].rgbtGreen = average;
        image[i][j].rgbtBlue = average;
    }
}
}

// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < (width / 2); j++)
    {
        RGBTRIPLE s = image[i][j];
        image[i][j] = image[i][width - (j + 1)];
        image[i][width - (j + 1)] = s;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The parameter has height/width indexes, but you appear to have them reversed in the loop (width/height).

Comment: Please do not add pictures of your errors. Instead simply copy the plain text into the question. Or in case of a CS50 checker error message, you could post a link to the test result.

Comment: You mixed limits for height/width. Your source index is off by 1. And you also forgot to swap the pixels from left to the right half

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I fixed it, but the error still appears

Comment: I don't see an error in the updated code. Please try to create a [mcve]. Side note: I notice in `grayscale` you are not calculating the avg correctly because of a missing `()`. It should be like `round((r+g+b) / 3.0)`